# How to write the below code in Java 8 using lambda expressions?

Tags: java-8

I have the following classes:

```java
package com.test.api;

public class Driver {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    
  // getters, setters
    
}
```

```java
package com.test.api;

import java.util.List;


public class Vehicle {
    
    private String name;
    private String make;
    private int modelyear;
    private List<Driver> drivers;
   // getters, setters
}
```

```java
package com.test.api;

public class Data {
    
    private String driverName;
    private String vehicleName;
    private String gender;
    private boolean isDriverEligible;
    private boolean isRecentVehicle;
    // getters, setters
}
```

and I am currently doing this in traditional way without lamdas and streams:

```java
private static List<Data> map(List<Vehicle> vehicleList) {
    List<Data> dataList = null;
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicleList) {
        if ("BMW".equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getName())) {
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Driver driver : vehicle.getDrivers()) {
            if (driver.getAge() > 18 && vehicle.getModelyear() > 2016) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setDriverName(driver.getName());
            data.setLuxuryVehicle(true);
            data.setVehicleName(vehicle.getName());
            data.setDriverEligible(true);
            data.setRecentVehicle(true);
            dataList.add(data);

            }
            if (driver.getAge() > 18 && vehicle.getModelyear() < 2016) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setDriverName(driver.getName());
            data.setLuxuryVehicle(true);
            data.setVehicleName(vehicle.getName());
            data.setDriverEligible(true);
            data.setRecentVehicle(false);
            dataList.add(data);

            }
        }
        List<Response> response = service.update(dataList, vehicle);

        }
    }
    return dataList;

    }
```

So I wanted to iterate through List of Drivers for each Vehicle and based on the conditions, I need to map some data. And then once all the data is populated to the `"Data"` List, I am updating it in to a service. Everything looks good but I wanted to refactor it using java 8.How can I do it?

Comment: Your `response` seems to be discarded and the `dataList` is discarded also (if there are more than one vehicle that has the name "BWM", the previous result is discarded). Is it expected?

Answer (score 0):

```java
final Vehicle[] vehicle = new Vehicle[1];
vehicleList.stream()
           .filter(v -> "BMW".equalsIgnoreCase(v.getName()))
           .map(v -> {vehicle[0] = v; return v;})
           .flatMap(v -> v.getDrivers().stream())
           .filter(driver -> driver.getAge() > 18)
           .map(driver -> {
               Data data = new Data();
               data.setDriverName(driver.getName());
               data.setLuxuryVehicle(true);
               data.setVehicleName(vehicle[0].getName());
               data.setDriverEligible(true);
               data.setRecentVehicle(vehicle[0].getModelyear() > 2016);
               return data;
           })
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior notice: If you are running this against a database, it's HIGHLY RECOMMENDED to do that with some SQL or stored procedures. Messing with data in the application is not considered a good practice unless it's absolutely necessary.

The idea of using stream is to describe filtering and mapping in distinct blocks.

Let's start simple, from the inner loop.

```java
private static List<Data> map(List<Vehicle> vehicleList) {
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    vehicleList.stream().filter(vehicle -> "BMW".equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getName())).forEach(vehicle -> {
        dataList.addAll(
            return vehicle.getDrivers().stream()
                .filter(driver -> driver.getAge() > 18)
                .map(driver -> {
                    Data data = new Data();
                    data.setDriverName(driver.getName());
                    data.setLuxuryVehicle(true);
                    data.setVehicleName(vehicle.getName());
                    data.setDriverEligible(true);
                    if (vehicle.getModelyear() > 2016) {
                        data.setRecentVehicle(true);
                        return data;
                    }
                    if (vehicle.getModelyear() < 2016) {
                        data.setRecentVehicle(false);
                        return data;
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(it -> it != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
        List<Response> response = service.update(dataList, vehicle);
    });
    return dataList;
}
```

We have replaced `for` loops with a stream. Since we are going to add it into a list, we can map the elements into target elements, and then collect them and call `addAll(.)` to append them to the list.

Then we can make it to the outer loop:

```java
private static List<Data> map(List<Vehicle> vehicleList) {
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    vehicleList.stream().filter(vehicle -> "BMW".equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getName())).forEach(vehicle -> {
        dataList.addAll(
            return vehicle.getDrivers().stream()
                .filter(driver -> driver.getAge() > 18)
                .map(driver -> {
                    Data data = new Data();
                    data.setDriverName(driver.getName());
                    data.setLuxuryVehicle(true);
                    data.setVehicleName(vehicle.getName());
                    data.setDriverEligible(true);
                    if (vehicle.getModelyear() > 2016) {
                        data.setRecentVehicle(true);
                        return data;
                    }
                    if (vehicle.getModelyear() < 2016) {
                        data.setRecentVehicle(false);
                        return data;
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(it -> it != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
        List<Response> response = service.update(dataList, vehicle);
    });
    return dataList;
}
```

By simply replacing the `for` loop with a stream and substitute it with `forEach` is enough. We can also filter out the unwanted elements before `forEach` with `filter`.

Comment: It does not compile for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's is how I would do it:

```java
static void inJava8(List<Vehicle> vehicleList) {
    Predicate<Vehicle> isBMW = vehicle -> "BMW".equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.getName());
    Predicate<Vehicle> isRecentvehicle = vehicle -> vehicle.getModelyear() > 2016;

    Map<Boolean, List<Vehicle>> isRecentToVehicleMap = vehicleList.stream()
                                                                  .filter(isBMW::test)
                                                                  .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(isRecentvehicle));

    isRecentToVehicleMap.get(true).stream()
                                  .forEach(vehicle -> processVehicle(vehicle, Test::recentBMWDataCOnstructor));

    isRecentToVehicleMap.get(false).stream()
                                   .forEach(vehicle -> processVehicle(vehicle, Test::notRecentBMWDataCOnstructor));
}

public static void processVehicle(Vehicle vehicle, Function<Driver, Data> function) {
    // this predicate should be at class level to avoid creating per vehicle
    Predicate<Driver> isAgeEligile = driver -> driver.getAge() > 18;

    List<Data> dataList = vehicle.getDrivers()
                                 .stream()
                                 .filter(isAgeEligile::test)
                                 .map(function::apply)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    service.update(dataList, vehicle);
}

public static Data recentBMWDataCOnstructor(Driver driver) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setDriverName(driver.getName());
    data.setLuxuryVehicle(true);
    data.setVehicleName("BMW");
    data.setDriverEligible(true);
    data.setRecentVehicle(false);

    return data;
}

public static Data notRecentBMWDataCOnstructor(Driver driver) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setDriverName(driver.getName());
    data.setLuxuryVehicle(true);
    data.setVehicleName("BMW");
    data.setDriverEligible(true);
    data.setRecentVehicle(false);

    return data;
}
```